# Prove that $\left\{{n+1}\atop{k+1}\right\}=\sum_{i=k}^{n}{\left(k+1\right)^{n-i}\left\{{i}\atop{k}\right\}}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

**Question**

I want to prove the following well known expression for Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind:

$$
\left\{{n+1}\atop{k+1}\right\}=\sum_{i=k}^{n}{\left(k+1\right)^{n-i}\left\{{i}\atop{k}\right\}}
$$

**My Solution**

*Left hand side*

We divide $n+1$ kids into $k+1$ non - empty groups. The number of groupings are given by the definition of Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind:

$$
\left\{{n+1}\atop{k+1}\right\}
$$

*Right hand side*

Suppose the kids are assigned number $1,…,n+1$ from youngest to oldest. The youngest kid in a group become the group’s captain. The term in right hand side gives us the number of possible groupings such that the oldest captain wear number $i+1$:

$$
\left(k+1\right)^{n-i}\left\{{i}\atop{k}\right\}
$$

Explanation: for kid $i+1$ to be the oldest captain, kid $1,…,i$ must be divided into the other $k$ groups and each group has at least one of these kids. Kid $i+2,…,n+1$ can join any of the $k+1$ groups.

If we sum up all the number for all possible value of $i$, we get the number of all possible groupings:

$$
\sum_{i=k}^{n}{\left(k+1\right)^{n-i}\left\{{i}\atop{k}\right\}}
$$

**Conclusion**

Because both left and right hand side are use to count the same objects they must be equal. I need your help to verify if my solution is correct and also if there’s other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seek to verify that

$${n+1\brace k+1} = \sum_{q=k}^n (k+1)^{n-q} {q\brace k}.$$

We get for the RHS using the OGF of the Stirling numbers of the second
kind

$$\sum_{q=k}^n
[z^{n-q}] \frac{1}{1-(k+1)z}
[z^q] \prod_{r=1}^k \frac{z}{1-rz}$$

Now we may lower $q$ to zero as the second term makes for a zero
contribution in the added range:

$$\sum_{q=0}^n
[z^{n-q}] \frac{1}{1-(k+1)z}
[z^q] \prod_{r=1}^k \frac{z}{1-rz}
= [z^n] \frac{1}{1-(k+1)z}
\prod_{r=1}^k \frac{z}{1-rz}
\\ = [z^{n+1}] \frac{z}{1-(k+1)z}
\prod_{r=1}^k \frac{z}{1-rz}
= [z^{n+1}] \prod_{r=1}^{k+1} \frac{z}{1-rz}
= {n+1\brace k+1}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Hey Marko, thank you for the answer. Appreciate it! +1

Comment: You're welcome.